# Filtrar solo datos numéricos

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tengo un vector columna compuesto por caractéres y por valores numéricos algo así:

```
1234
5678
ABCD
EFGH
9101
```

El caso es que necesito filtrar estos datos con el fin de que solo me queden estas filas:

```
1234
5678
9101
```

He intentado utilizar la función `startswith` pero no he podido lograr mi objetivo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si por "vector columna" te refieres a una `Series` pandas como la siguiente:

```python
>>> print(df)
0    1234
1    5678
2    ABCD
3    EFGH
4    9101
dtype: object
```

Entonces puedes quedarte sólo con las filas que sean numéricas con esta expresión:

```python
>>> df[df.str.isnumeric()]
0    1234
1    5678
4    9101
dtype: object
```

Si te refieres a una lista python normal, como esta:

```python
>>> lista
['1234', '5678', 'ABCD', 'EFGH', '9101']
```

Entonces una *list comprehension* puede servirte:

```python
>>> [dato for dato in lista if dato.isdigit()]
['1234', '5678', '9101']
```

O si quieres que la lista sea ya de enteros en vez de cadenas:

```python
>>> [int(dato) for dato in lista if dato.isdigit()]
[1234, 5678, 9101]
```